npm run build:server fails keeps exiting in docker environment
I am trying to deploy an application built using ES-build and Node.js. For some reason the npm run build:server keep exiting in the docker environment during docker build. Localhost it runs smoothly, as well as when I try running it using docker exec.
my package.json:
{
  "name": "nodejs-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/app.mjs",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:server": "node build.mjs",
    "watch:restart-server": "nodemon --config nodemon.json",
    "build:server": "node build.mjs",
    "start:dev": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:server watch:restart-server",
    "start:prod": "pm2 start dist/app.cjs --name myApp"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^8.1.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "docusign-esign": "^5.20.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "env": "^0.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "joi": "^17.12.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.2.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "pm2": "^5.3.1",
    "winston": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/docusign-esign": "^5.19.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.6",
    "esbuild": "^0.19.11",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}

my build.mjs file:
import * as esbuild from "esbuild";
import "dotenv/config";


async function build() {

let ctx;

try {
  ctx = await esbuild.context({
    entryPoints: ["src/app.ts"],
    bundle: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    minify: false,
    platform: "node",
    target: ["node18.17.0"],
    packages: "external",
    tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
    define: {
      "process.env.MODE": "process.env.MODE",
      "process.env.PORT": "process.env.PORT",
      "process.env.BASE_URL":"process.env.BASE_URL",
    },
    

    outfile: "dist/app.cjs",
  });

  await ctx.watch();
  if (process.env.MODE === "production") {
    process.exit(1);
  } else {
    console.log("Watching server...");
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error("An error occurred:", error);
  process.exit(1);
};
};


build()


Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:18.17.0
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./code/package.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install pm2 -g 
COPY ./code .
COPY ./.env ./
RUN npm run build:server
EXPOSE 3030
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "dist/app.cjs"]

The MODE=production is already mentioned in env. I tried using different users, different shells, none worked. Strange thing is that it works perfectly fine when I do docker exec  npm run build:server, but using Dockerfile it doesn't. My node and npm versions are also same in both the environments.
This is the error I'm facing:
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build:server" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
As a workaround, I have been building it locally and uploading the build files to container, then run the start command via dockerfile.
How do I build the application using Dockerfile itself, without the need to manually build it?
